$||e^{A}x|| < ||x||$ for self-adjoint $A$ with non-positive spectrum
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $A: H \rightarrow H$ be a self-adjoint operator with spectrum $\sigma(A) \subseteq [-M, 0]$ for some $M > 0$. Further assume that $0 \in \sigma(A)$, but $\ker(A) = \{0\}$.
Using the spectral theorem, it can fairly easily be shown that $||e^A x|| \lneq ||x||$ for all $x \in H$. Note that this is a strict inequality — the analogous “less than or equal to” inequality is much easier to prove. But that feels like too heavy of machinery for such a simple property. Is there a way to show this without appealing to the spectral theorem?
My best attempt is to write:
$$||e^A x||^2 = \langle e^{2A} x, x \rangle = ||x||^2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!} \langle A^nx , x \rangle$$
Since $A$ is negative semidefinite and $\sigma(A^n) = \sigma(A)^n$, we see that $\langle A^nx, x \rangle$ is positive for all even $n$ and negative for all odd $n$. However, I can’t figure out how to show that the negative contribution from the odd terms outweigh the positive contribution from the even terms. Any help would be appreciated! I’m sure there’s some knockout property that I’m simply missing.

We can instead use
$$e^A = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{A}{n} \right)^n.$$
This reduces the problem to showing that $\| 1 + \frac{A}{n} \| \le 1$ for sufficiently large $n$ but this is clear once $n \ge M$, provided we know that the norm of a self-adjoint operator is its spectral radius. Although if we know that we can just compute the spectral radius of $e^A$ and hence its norm, I guess.
Edit: To prove the weak inequality we can use a variation of the idea above. If $\| e^A x \| = \| x \|$ then writing $e^A = (e^{\frac{A}{n}})^n$ gives, together with the fact that we also know the same inequality for $\frac{A}{n}$, that $\| e^{\frac{A}{n}} x \| = \| x \|$. Squaring and expanding to second order gives
$$\| x \|^2 + \frac{\langle x, Ax \rangle}{n} + \frac{3}{2n^2} \| Ax \|^2 + O \left( \frac{1}{n^3} \right) = \| x \|^2$$
and taking $n$ sufficiently large gives first that $\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0$ and then that $\| Ax \|^2 = 0$, hence $Ax = 0$, but this was ruled out by hypothesis.

Thanks for the suggestion! However, this argument only shows the inequality $||e^A x|| \leq ||x||$. I’m trying to show the strict inequality.

@Joe: I've edited in an argument.

Perhaps an ODE approach works. Let $f(t) = e^{tA}x$. Let $g(t) = \|f(t)\|^2$. Then
\begin{align}
g'(t) &= (f'(t), f(t)) + (f(t), f'(t)) \\
&= (Af(t), f(t)) + (f(t), Af(t)) \\
&= 2(Af(t), f(t)) \\
&\leq 0. \\
\end{align}
Thus $g(0) \geq g(t)$ for all $t \geq 0$, i.e.,
$$\|x\|^2 \geq \|e^{tA}x\|^2.$$

Thanks for the suggestion! However, this argument only shows the inequality $||e^A x|| \leq ||x||$. I’m trying to show the strict inequality.

From my argument, we have $$|e^{A}x|^2 = |x|^2 + \int_{0}^{1}2(Ae^{sA}x, e^{sA}x),ds.$$ Is there any easy way to show $\int_{0}^{1}2(Ae^{sA}x, e^{sA}x),ds < 0$? It is sufficient to show merely that there is at least one $s \in [0, 1]$ such that $(Ae^{sA}x, e^{sA}x) < 0$. We must assume $x \neq 0$, for instance.

The operator $B:=-A$ is positive and its kernel is trivial by assumptions. There holds
$$\|e^{B}u\|^2=\langle e^{2B}u,u\rangle= \langle u,u\rangle +\sum_{n=1}^\infty {2^n\over n!}\langle B^{n}u,u\rangle \\
\ge \langle u,u\rangle+{2^2\over 2!}\langle B^2u,u\rangle=\|u\|^2+2\|Bu\|^2>\|u\|^2$$ For $x\neq 0$ let $u=e^{A}x,$ i.e. $x=e^{B}u.$ Then
$$\| x\|=\|e^{B}u\|>\|u\|=\|e^{A}x\|$$
